# restore an azure blob snapshot using c# library

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am writing a CLI utility that does a lot of different things, but what I'm struggling with right now is I have a known blob.  For that blob, I want to restore a snapshot that was taken of that blob

```
await foreach (var snapshot in containerClient.GetBlobsAsync(
    BlobTraits.All,
    BlobStates.Snapshots,
    blobPath))
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"found blob {snapshot.Name} - {snapshot.Snapshot}");
    if (DecideIfRightSnapshot(snapshot)) {
        BlobClient snapshotBlob = containerClient.GetBlobClient(snapshot.Name);
        _logger.LogInformation($"found snapshot {snapshotBlob.Uri}");
        await sourceBlob.StartCopyFromUriAsync(snapshotBlob.Uri);
    }
    break;
}
```

First, the filter isn't working right because the last blob in the list is always the base blob.  But I can work around that one.

The real issue i'm struggling with is the proper way to restore a blob from a snapshot using the libs?  I'm really concerned because the `.Uri` function always returns the base file's uri, even if its a snapshot.  I was lead to believe the URI would be something like this

`https://me.blob.core.windows.net/myapp/doc?snapshot=2020-12-16T17:07:44.1076450Z`

but thats not the URI thats getting logged.  Am i supposed to construct the full URI myself?

In all the searches they refer to this as "promoting" a snapshot.  But I can't find a "promote" method in the API.

Am i doing this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the new version of blob storage sdk: [Azure.Storage.Blobs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs/12.7.0), then you should construct the full URI by yourself. The sample code like below:

```
//other code

await foreach (var snapshot in containerClient.GetBlobsAsync(
BlobTraits.All,
BlobStates.Snapshots,
blobPath))
{

_logger.LogInformation($"found blob {snapshot.Name} - {snapshot.Snapshot}");


if(DecideIfRightSnapshot(snapshot)) {
    BlobClient snapshotBlob = containerClient.GetBlobClient(snapshot.Name);

    //construct the snapshot url
    var snapshot_uri = snapshotBlob.Uri.ToString() + "?snapshot=" + snapshot.Snapshot;


    _logger.LogInformation($"found snapshot {snapshot_uri }");
    await sourceBlob.StartCopyFromUriAsync(snapshot_uri);
 }
 break;
}
```

**For promoting**, it means you restore the snapshot via azure portal. It's a UI operation and actually it calls the [Put Blob From URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob-from-url) api. And currently, there is no such method in sdk.

But if you're using some old packages like [WindowsAzure.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/), it has many methods to operate with snapshot, see [this article](https://blog.maximerouiller.com/post/creating-and-retrieving-snapshots-from-azure-blob-storage-files/). Note: it's not recommended to use the old packages.